# Why does the Portuguese language sound similar to French language to me?

Tags: phonetics, french, spanish, portuguese

I thought Portuguese would sound very close to Spanish. However, to me, it sounds more like French?

Why is that?

Comment: Probably because it has nasal vowels and a uvular /ʀ/. It sounds like Russian to a lot of people as well, since it has lots of reduced vowels that lead to consonant clusters, and lots of sibilants.

Comment: Certainly not Brazilian Portuguese. Do you mean Iberian Portuguese??

Comment: With possible answers like Janus Bahs Jacquet's above, it's really unclear to me why people would want to close this as "opinion-based". It is clear that some languages sound more similar to each other than others, and it is a task of linguistics to explain why.

Comment: Nasal vowels and /ʒ/ are likely a big part of it.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, Brazilian Portuguese sounds nothing like French.

Comment: I'm sorry but I speak both languages fluently and I just don't see it or hear it. There can be similar sounds but the overall sound system is very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nasal vowels, like the other replies said, are probably why. The pronouns are also similar. Je, Tu, Il/Elle/On, Nous, Vous, Ils/Elles for French and Eu, Tu, Ele/Ela, Nós, Eles,Elas.